# what does it mean if `which X` finds something but executing `X` fails?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

Specifically python:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ ll `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 18 10:26 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

$ python
The program 'python3' is currently not installed.

$ ll /usr/local/bin/python
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory

$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

$ python2.7 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I don't understand why `python` won't run python2.7 here -- isn't the symlink pointing to python2.7?

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/local/bin/python` that is a symlink to `python3` perhaps?

Comment: @dobey seems like no, updated the post

Comment: What is the output of `whereis python` and `echo $PATH` commands?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu echo $PATH has a lot of stuff, anything in particular? grepping for python didn't yield anything, if that helps

Comment: Yes, the order of directories from the `PATH` and the output of `type python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have an alias. Try `type -a python`

Comment: Nicely done: `python is aliased to ``python3'`

Comment: so `which` doesn't go through aliases?

Comment: clearly not. [man which](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/which.1.html)

Comment: That's clear? If you say so man.

Comment: you don't have to believe me. look at your own terminal.

Comment: What I'm saying is that aliases aren't mentioned at all on that page. So it doesn't seem very clear at all.